# How to convert this sql query to JPA criteria

Tags: postgresql, jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I would like to do a string search on all the columns in my table or view in my database.

Below is my SQL query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_FAVORITE_MOVIES as t 
where t::text like '%srk%'
```

The above query would do a search of the string in all the columns of the table.
How to do the same with JPA criteriaBuilder API?

I tried using the [like](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string#Criteria_Query_String_Expressions_) operation but it seems like I have to do a string search for each and every column. Is there a way to do a search string in all  columns at once.

Comment: What have you tried when you attempted this yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible with JPA. You must query all fields separately. Or you may just trigger your SQL query as a native query from JPA.